# Error occur: undefined reference when trying to ndk-build to run tflite example

Tags: android, c++, tensorflow, android-ndk

### Problem

I'm trying to NDK build simple tflite example code.

When I build, this error is occured.

`error: undefined reference to 'tflite::InterpreterBuilder::operator()(std::__1::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter, std::__1::default_delete<tflite::Interpreter> >*)'`

### My workflow

First, I build tflite. I type command `bazel build --config=elinux_aarch64 -c opt //tensorflow/lite:libtensorflowlite.so` and libtensorflow.so file is created.

And Secondely, I prepare tflite code.

```c
  // Load model
  std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile(model_file.c_str());

  // Build the interpreter
  tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
  std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter;
  tflite::InterpreterBuilder(*model, resolver)(&interpreter);    <<<<<<----- This is where the error occurs. 

  interpreter->AllocateTensors();

  // Set input
  float* input = interpreter->typed_input_tensor<float>(0);
  for(int y=0; y<height; y++)
  {
    for(int x=0; x<width; x++)
    {
      *(input + y*width + x) = ((float)img.data[3*y*width + 3*x]);
      *(input + y*width + x + 1 * height*width) = ((float)img.data[3*y*width + 3*x + 1]);
      *(input + y*width + x + 2 * height*width) = ((float)img.data[3*y*width + 3*x + 2]);
    }
  }

  TfLiteTensor* output_tensor = nullptr;
  interpreter->Invoke();
  output_tensor = interpreter->tensor(interpreter->outputs()[0]);
```

and then, I link the libtensorflow.so file.

I add two line in my Android.mk

```
TFLITE_INSTALL_PATH := packages/apps/3rdparty/tflite
LOCAL_LDLIBS:= $(TFLITE_INSTALL_PATH)/lib_android/libtensorflowlite.so
```

### What I tried to solve the error.

#### 1) change ndk version

Now I'm using ndk ver 21, and I try another version(13, 15, 18) too.

#### 2) re-build tensorflow lite

I add option such as `--config=monolithic`, `--config=dynamic_kernels` and `--cxxopt=--std=c++14`
And I also change option `--config=elinux_aarch64` to `--config=android_arm64`

### Question

In this situation, Is there anything to check? I don't know what to do anymore.
Is this problem of Android.mk setting? or build bazel setting?

please help